# Chaining static .plugin() class method to extend instance APIs multiple times

Tags: typescript

I've a plugin architecture which I allows me to do this

```
const fooPlugin = () => ({ foo: 'foo' })
const barPlugin = () => ({ bar: 'bar' })

const BaseWithPlugin = Base.plugin(fooPlugin)
const baseWithPlugin = new BaseWithPlugin()
baseWithPlugin.foo // ✅ string

const BaseWithPlugins = Base.plugin([fooPlugin, barPlugin])
const baseWithPlugins = new BaseWithPlugins()
baseWithPlugins.foo // ✅ string
baseWithPlugins.bar // ✅ string
```

But it fails at doing this

```
const BaseWithPlugins2 = Base.plugin(fooPlugin).plugin(barPlugin)
const baseWithPlugins2 = new BaseWithPlugins2()
baseWithPlugins2.foo // ❌ Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'plugin<() => { bar: string; }>.BaseWithPlugins & { bar: string; }'.
baseWithPlugins2.bar // ✅ string
```

If I create another class which extends `BaseWithPlugin` and has the exact same implementation for the static `plugin` method, I get the expected result

```
class Workaround extends BaseWithPlugin {
  static plugin<T extends TestPlugin | TestPlugin[]>(plugin: T) {
    const currentPlugins = this.plugins;

    const WorkaroundWithPlugins = class extends this {
      static plugins = currentPlugins.concat(plugin);
    };

    type Extension = ReturnTypeOf<T>;
    return WorkaroundWithPlugins as typeof WorkaroundWithPlugins & Constructor<Extension>;
  }
}

const BaseWithPlugins3 = Workaround.plugin(barPlugin)
const baseWithPlugins3 = new BaseWithPlugins3()
baseWithPlugins3.foo // ✅ string
baseWithPlugins3.bar // ✅ string
```

I'm hoping to find a way that will not require that workaround. This looks like a bug reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863). A few workarounds were mentioned in the thread, but I don't think any of them is applicable to my case.

Here is [the Playground with the full code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=79&ssc=1&pln=80&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCigG0BrCEALijWACcEUBzAXSoFcUSUkB3FAbjwBfQXlCQoAQTAIAogA9gEdMhRZcxMpWp0GLKgEMUIKCLHhoAFQg0ACgBs2jBuoAUBKAxpGAxhCoAQgZoEAA0HkjwqmhUcIioaHgAlFgAfFIyCkoqqFAAPlAcACYQAGYMEEWC4tAAwgl0bD7ASLQAPJbp2CgQPFCuAHRDBrSMMVBGIETMKZjplqIA9ABUywTLUAACBmzAABatUHvAwGAxi4vePiRIAG4QtKX2vAM+SAC2i2whtGiLAEwADkBAHZ-gBGQGLABWPgM9gAXustiFoMdTudLsADNc7g8ni83p8DIsAKwABgAzCDSUCAGyLcFU-4Uyn-daLcwSACqKFUliQAEkUEpfhBmqo2rzVF1+tLchBFMoihhJh4APz9EaMNjvZTAKjylCzdK3JAIIoeKg9e60FKK7IqrWjXX6qgMUoPKDC0UhCWoE1QM0WqAXKDAND2BgGooINAGABG9ggAFooz1rUgUxxvpUNd6RQ8-fEUFaoDaHqIalJjAAxDj+tTYQbDUbjSaByZVixQABKEGAbFoKEsFhgpQ6UAdyowkjrDZL+RrIHrKEb01llinSpQTrnK4Xqnz-cHw9HkA6qTLW+nu9n87XJem+aNAp9RfFJbaJ6HI4sHSIFBdQTB5mFSK9CGtCBbVERUwFaYAoB8exggwIIQlwDxvEQHwoDARxnHQKhrDsAiGGmdRpkEQhsIQXD8KcBhJ1vJ0SOABxGLUAo2I4wiN1cBjCOIlJ8EIQg3nQRCfCHWh9V4rx1H2OMBkErxRDEpCGigdCIAAdQQfZ5PQdRkNQ7dHQwJSMFEjSdAMHC8LI4zsGk2hZJFIy0FeVA4WAASnKSaixLMDxCGrLJlDQVR1B-M8xwnTogsIWTTzUHT9MMpzVUsiwkFKbTgj0gy9k8qAADIoHqSTaCaFp2ginIUFSIKhDwLDsQckpSh2ewI1cLqeojWIogSETQqgFLfyQlC0AwGBmiQEgDIyvYABEykGjAWMsvY40w2zNOq2rWlcSIS3GOJonUHAhDGg6aLYSBaFcGAE2hT8BlQhBGBQVwbtCKABrYXq0ABs7oiSQLxsIVqNLMGG2vEhoaoW57wYSYbzuu279rEqyBnR5yoEJtB1LEsMDDAfCTFU9BxrDdEzgoC4rhuW0CR4bziUZOlKQAFlJcEwXGiSaGm1CqpoFG6sU3avNFxpUYmHLIDygqQiS8XZslxW6pUrKBlKVpZBxPZ-M4tJcY0173uaT7Zu+36rIB2nXGd4mRvQSHNdulrEY987MeiQRWrwBWoCNpAjLcQM-ojpAkCoABySOk9MJIw60hMRmj5tY5wKBs9oZOi7T262vD9Litz9WIH1zjXEjoyM-D7OQhWmuej6KvMobjO26K3vCMNhPQ0WKBAFByHR6CYCutJ7kqsvUHT68I1wiCbpyAaLoyZkzyTC8Kjul+6Xpa+Pzi0Fcfuj+rg3I7Hyfp70PAB4vwivKLx+p6ll-97Fhenl-jL0KqvBgjcE7NzAb9HeAV-6ITfnfS+wDT7d1vkPLw-xr6v3QYvZBI8kCP0ADLkUBbC0EiA8UAUAU4JzTkUJANhyxIEQoqOMiFcjViTrTNo19LYFyLlQX+TB+CmFSAMQBS8Kr8JGII3QwjTBJwGDg9uSCP7-AGF-MMP85GMDamGPAYZdIwF7AAaUkL2GA3IAByq1tIAE0oAAFlJBWO5JIAAMu4hxtReyyEkJYQUViADiUgrHeisSmAIshLC6VkLIMJtR3GSAAMrJIMePQUUBLAAAlAkmKybk5JUBknZMse42xViYBbiiVAKxshaiyFSeYux6SoBtTgghLWGBdKtBICMJAxRzIznPqolwNlaL0ScsxHcrEbDsSckuHiTl+K02ElbQ6YtXLuXmZfWWylaak39kjA+PTaB9PIcUd+CkXIzS2jMnae0bIaQmY5XZLkZJyQNhJXy5tCJQzhmTMKPYGpRVyNgWKf5IDjkvJrSaw4oCnPOQM3cVzjLBHDLlfKiL+mXNGcZCqOtpatDaCCmUftQ6V1wZ5Sk6hsUXN3NA1wsDOItyzlSrKNLUEjIwegSk2DEE8rQJSAh39n6zwFXgj+wrNHj20TPRgQA). I've also [created a repository with 2 failing test cases that reproduce the problem](https://github.com/gr2m/javascript-plugin-architecture-with-typescript-definitions/pulls). I cannot figure out how to make the chainging of `.plugin().plugin()` or `.plugin().defaults()` work, or if it's at all possible with today's TypeScript. I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's [the Playground with solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCigG0BrCEALijWACcEUBzAXSoFcUSUkB3FAbjwBfQXlCQoAQTAIAogA9gEdMhRZcxMpWp0GLKgEMUIKCLHhoAFQg0ACgBs2jBuoAUBKAxpGAxhCoAQgZoEAA0HkjwqmhUcIioaHgAlFgAfFIyCkoqqFAAPlAcACYQAGYMEEWC4tAAwgl0bD7ASLQAPJbp2CgQPFCuAHRDBrSMMVBGIETMKZjplqIA9ABUywTLUAACBmzAABatUHvAwGAxi4vePiRIAG4QtKX2vAM+SAC2i2whtGiLAEwADkBAHZ-gBGQGLABWPgM9gAXustiFoMdTudLsADNc7g8ni83p8DIsAKwABgAzCDSUCAGyLcFU-4Uyn-daLcwSACqKFUliQAEkUEpfhBmqo2rzVF1+tLchBFMoihhJh4APz9EaMNjvZTAKjylCzdK3JAIIoeKg9e60FKK7IqrWjXX6qgMUoPKDC0UhCWoE1QM0WqAXKDAND2BgGooINAGABG9ggAFooz1rUgUxxvpUNd6RQ8-fEUFaoDaHqIalJjAAxDj+tTYQbDUbjSaByZVixQABKEGAbFoKEsFhgpQ6UAdyowkjrDZL+RrIHrKEb01llinSpQTrnK4Xqnz-cHw9HkA6qTLW+nu9n87XJem+aNAp9RfFJbaJ6HI4sHSIFBdQTB5mFSK9CGtCBbVERUwFaYAoB8exggwIIQlwDxvEQHwoDARxnHQKhrDsAiGGmdRpkEQhsIQXD8KcBg2gAZW3R0MHqdBGmaVo2kmdIADINAYwj22MCihFCKAbx3J0SOABxGLUAp5MUwiN1cfY4yoZipJEhhiJSfBCEIN4uKQodaH1NSvHULS0AGfT0FEEykIaKB0IgAB1BB9hs9B1GQ1C2JncM9jjTDXJo7EcLwsiAuwHxLOs+KHLMuFgFcJykmokyzA8QhqyyZQ0FUdQfzPMcJ06XLCCs081E8ny-NSiYMBqJBSg84JvN8vZ-IwITOJoWgmhadpipyFBUlyoQ8CwmK6KgEpSh2ewI1cFa1ojWIogSIyCqgerfyQlC0AwGAeJIXzmr2AARMptowW8nXsyKorMkaxtaVxIhLcY4midQcCEA6opMtA2EgWhXBgBNoU-AZUIQRgUFcEGpK2th1rQKS-uiJIcsOwg5tcswSfm0yGlGniYfxhJdv+4HQfewrwoc+mEqgTm0BckywwMMB8JMJzElcsN0TOCgLiuG5bQJHhXg+RYSXBOlKQAFlJcEwUOz7EKC87hu48a7PZpWuJp03gnDCxOu6kJatO1Djat1pHNSgZSlaWQcT2LL4rSVmTLhhHmiR86UbR+y9PizT2bxvb0EJp3QdmynuaTgGs8EOa8H1qBvaQfy3EDdHC6QJAqEaaBQfz9yExGEvmzLnAoEb2gqAAcg7rvTCSeaC6avrm4diAPaU1wi-8geC8bkJbtHno+mHlrJ4H+ferXwivcr0NFigQBQch0egmEH9zV-61rsE8ifCNcIhp-iqSO-8mZ6-MzfF+v8tejH7+lJoFcBvHqADRK7yQPvI+J89B4C-iPT2HcoHHxGrAj+NB-4IMAf8dQt8nJT0rjPO+DBXCv3irPBuoCsGiRwd0P+l8Br-GAXAqh28vD-AgVAwAMuRQFsLQSIDxQBQC7kXPuRQkA2HLEgRCio4yIVyNWLuTk2jAKDm3DuVBUFMH4KYVIAwGGtSEuokYmjdDaNMF3AYLCF7UPYQMJBYYUFmMYHgIAA).

```js
class Base {
  static plugin<S extends Constructor<any> & { plugins: any[] }, T extends TestPlugin | TestPlugin[]>(this: S, plugin: T) {
    const currentPlugins = this.plugins;

    const BaseWithPlugins = class extends this {
      static plugins = currentPlugins.concat(plugin);
    };

    type Extension = ReturnTypeOf<T>;
    return BaseWithPlugins as typeof BaseWithPlugins & Constructor<Extension>;
  }
}
```

The part you're missing is that you should let `plugin` static function also infer the type of `this`.

Comment: I could not yet check it in detail, but it looks like it does the trick! I'll report back once I could put it to proper testing. Thanks a lot!